# Android: Why data binding not forcing NullPointerException even if object is null

Tags: android, android-layout, data-binding

I am not sure why data binding not allowing crash even if the object is null, Some time it's not okay to avoid null pointer exceptions, as a  result user might see empty data or get confused by seeing empty TextFild.

**Eg:**

```
android:text="@{user.lastName}"
```

If above user object is null, then we will see empty textView, where user can think they don't have the last name in database/network server.

Is there any parameter where we can force NullPointerException if the object is null?

Comment: what happens if you set the text of your element directly to `null`? Well one of the biggest advantages of Data Binding is to avoid Null pointer problems. Maybe because the framework just create the view without asking about the data and after that tries to get the data no null pointer is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

you can check nullPointerException for variable in **getter** method of var 
or even set **null condition in databinding** set text like bellow

```
android:text="@{user.lastName != null ? user.lastName : "unknown text" }"
```

Comment: what if user object is null?

Comment: @jitsm555 check your user variable for nullPointerException when setting properties of that , cause when you change values of user property then databinding in layout called

Comment: I am not sure, how we can do that, because that response directly goes to your layout.

Comment: your response goes to layout after change or set value to that so you can check null condition before set or change value to user property